# Decrease the number of visible labels under Ext JS 4 chart

Tags: javascript, charts, label, extjs4

I'm writing Ext JS 4 line chart component. It works all fine, but when I display labels under axis they are just too dense. I won't the number of visible labels to decrease. How to do that? Here's my code for the axis:

```
{
    type: 'Category',
    position: 'bottom',
    fields: ['date'],
    grid: true,
    label: {
        field: 'label',
        rotate: { degrees:315 },
        renderer: function(item) {
            var date = new Date(item);
            /* parseIntToStringWithZeros is a custom method somewhere else */
            var day = parseIntToStringWithZeros(date.getDate());
            var month = parseIntToStringWithZeros(date.getMonth());
            result = day + '-' + month;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest to avoid using ExtJS chart system - they are not very mature yet. Try out [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com), it's opensource proj, free for non-commercial use. You can adopt it, create a customized component based off highcharts, and all the chart system will be in your ExtJS without any troubles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to use a "Numeric" axis instead of a "Category" axis a start (not sure what your data looks like, but you might need to convert times to values to get it to work).

With the numeric axis you are supposed to be able to set the number of major tick values (where the grid lines and labels appear), by setting the `steps` property in the axis config; however this doesn't always work.  A more surefire way is to override the `applyData` function which isn't documented so you need to search through the dev code to see what it's doing.

Also, to simply not render a particular label you can just return the empty string in the label renderer function.  e.g. if you only want an individual "month" to show up once in the above code you could do something like this..

```
label: {
    ....
    renderer: (function(){
       var lastRenderedMonth = '';
       return function(item){
           ... //your code above without the return..
           if(month == lastRenderedMonth)
              return "";
           lastRenderedMonth = month;
           return result;
       };
    })(),
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. Unfortunetly "months" in my case are all distinct and there are hundreds of them. Also I don't like the concept of overriding built-in functions. Also I've switched to HighCharts as sugested by Lionel Chan - ExtJS charting system really is annoying.

Comment: Good luck with that.  By the way - if you have hundred of unique months, it doesn't mean that they all need to be on the screen at once; it's just as easy to make it so that it will only render one label per year.  I've recently written a blog post on styling Ext Charts that might be useful http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/12/ext-js-4-stock-charts/